# Is it safe to get data from webpage and post it the server by using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm using ajax post some data to server, but first, I have to get the data from the webpage, for example from element

```
<span id="userMoney" value="1000">Money</span>
```

then I get the value for monery is 1000. next i send 1000 to the server. But here is the problem, user can easy modified the value and change 1000 to 100000 and server will get 100000 instead of the real value 1000. I think i have misused the ajax method. Can anyone give me some instruction?

Comment: Value for <span> is not standard way. You may use hidden input fields. And, to avoid user manipulating your hidden value you can use encryption.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will do as you said in the rest of the job.

Answer (score 3):

User can modify anything.
Therefore you should not trust to user's input and have a server-side validation.
Additionally you can use client-side validation which can potentially decrease the number of invalid requests to the server and offload it and also improve user's experience.

For the `span[value]` - I'd suggest to use `data-*` attributes instead,
like `<span id="userMoney" data-value="1000">Money</span>` because the `span` element is not intended to be used with `value` attribute by standards.

Comment: Yes, it's a part of the HTML5 and it's supported by all modern browsers.

Comment: @Evgeniy Naydenov. Thank you for your quick answer. I think it's right to a server-side validation.